# Problema com legenda no ggplot, usando duplo eixo y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de uma ajuda para resolver esse problema. Eu gostaria que a legenda apresentasse linhas pontilhadas (`linetype`), com pontos (`shape`) e cores (`colour`) iguais ao gráfico, porém este gráfico tem eixo duplo para y, por isso tive de adicionar as linhas separadas, pois há uma transformação, para ficarem na mesma escala de plotagem.

Na figura é possível observar que a legenda exibe apenas 1 tipo de `shape`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

clima<-structure(list(data=structure(c(15489,15490,15491,15492,
15493,15494,15495,15496,15497),class="Date"),VV=c(1.63,
2.87,2.33,2.33,2.43,0,3.07,4.47,4.47),Tmax=c(29.63,
30.63,30.77,29.97,29.65,30.1,31.13,31.53,31.3),Tmin=c(19.6,
15.32,15.38,14.98,14.8,15.05,15.57,15.77,15.65),Tmed=c(24.62,
22.98,23.08,22.48,20.9,22.58,23.35,23.65,23.48),UR=c(79.8,
74.6,73.3,79.3,77.6,72.9,70.5,70.4,72.8),Ubu=c(54.72,
46.31,42.61,35.19,29.59,27.15,23.05,16.77,11.97),P=c(0L,
0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L)),row.names=c(NA,-9L),class="data.frame")

clima$data<-ymd(clima$data)


 coef<-10

ggplot(clima,aes(x=data))+
  geom_line(aes(y=VV,colour="V. Vento"),size=1,linetype=2)+
  geom_point(aes(y=VV,colour="V. Vento"),shape=15,size=3)+  
  geom_line(aes(y=UR/coef,colour="UR ar"),linetype=1,size=1)+ 
  geom_point(aes(y=UR/coef,colour="UR ar"),shape=16,size=3)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression("Velocidade do Vento (m s"^2*")"),sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *coef,name=expression("Umidade relativa do ar (%)")))+
  scale_x_date("",date_labels ="%d/%m")+
  scale_colour_manual("",breaks=c("V. Vento","UR ar"),values = c("blue","black"))+
 #scale_shape_manual("",values=c(15,16))+
  #scale_linetype_manual("",values=c(2,1))+
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12,face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: A coluna `coef` não faz parte do data frame `clima`.

Comment: na verdade é apenas um dado para transformação, acho que esqueci de colocar :/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este tipo de problema é usualmente mais fácil de resolver se os dados estiverem no formato longo. Isso permite ter uma só variável a ser usada em `aes()` para `colour`, `linetype`, `shape` ou qualquer outra. O código pode ficar um pouco mais complicado (isto é questão de opinião, eu penso que não, que não fica) mas facilita quando se vai traçar o gráfico.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

clima$data<-ymd(clima$data)

coef <- 10

clima %>%
  select(data, VV, UR) %>%
  mutate(UR = UR/coef) %>%
  rename(`V. Vento` = VV,
         `UR ar` = UR) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("V. Vento", "UR ar"),
    names_to = "Variavel",
    values_to = "Valor"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(data, Valor, colour = Variavel)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Variavel), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Variavel), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression("Velocidade do Vento (m s"^2*")"),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *coef,name=expression("Umidade relativa do ar (%)")))+
  scale_x_date("", date_labels ="%d/%m") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2, 1)) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size=12,face = "bold"),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
    legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito obrigado, não uso tidyverse, por isso, pelo que vi, eu poderia ter resolvido com `reshape2::melt()` também, novamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: @JeanKarlos É verdade, o `reshape2::melt` também dá. Era o que eu usava antes de começar a habituar-me ao tidyverse. Demora algum tempo mas é muito mais flexível.